# How do I add color to page padding in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xaml, colors, xamarin.forms, padding

In my XAML I specify a padding at the top of my page using:

```
<d:BasePage.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color"
                iOS="#CF2129"/>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
            iOS="0, 20, 0, 0"/>
</d:BasePage.Padding>
```

The Thickness works but the Color does not. I get the error "Sequence contains no errors". Is there any way that I can add color to that padding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add color to the padding by setting the `BackgroundColor` of the element that is wrapped around it. In this case, you would set the `BasePage`'s `BackgroundColor` property.

**UPDATE:**

```
<d:BasePage BackgroundImage="Image">
    <ContentView>
        <ContentView.Padding>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0, 20, 0, 0"/>
        </ContentView.Padding>
        <ContentView.BackgroundColor>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color" iOS="#CF2129"/>
        </ContentView.BackgroundColor>

        ... Actual content ...

    </ContentView>
</d:BasePage>
```

Comment: @Loupi To elaborate, you can’t set color to padding but changing BackgroundColor of the parent view would show through where padding is - achieving same result. Useful for ”dyeing” your views when things act weird, haha.

Comment: This works but I also have a `BackgroundImage` so setting the page's `BackgroundColor` simply overrides the `BackgroundImage` which I don't want

Comment: Then you will need an additional element to wrap around your content. I updated the sample. I don't know what you're exactly trying to achieve but I'm fairly sure it can be solved by nesting some items and putting the padding, color and image on the appropriate elements.